# SQL Execute per each result row

Tags: sql, function, database-mail

I've been googling around for a bit but I can't seem to find an answer to this. I'm trying to use the Database Mail in SQL Server 2005 in a stored procedure where the idea is to send separate mail for each row in a query, each mail depending on an address residing in the rows.

Imagine for example 15 - 50 rows of product orders with the following data: **ID, CustomerName, CustomerEmail, ProductName, ProductCategory**. Each of the rows contains the customer email as well as the product category. I need to send a confirmation email to each of those customers using their personal data specific to their own rows, as well as the actual order mail to different company people depending on the product category.

How can I send Database Mail dynamically like this?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit 1:** Datasets etc are not an option, this has to be run exclusively on SQL Server 2005. I suppose I'll have to look into cursors then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, is not possible. Sending database mail is an invocation of a stored procedure and this is not allowed in queries, nor in functions.

You must send each mail one by one. You can use a cursor on the server in a stored procedure or iterate the table in the client.

Comment: Got back to this. Yes thanks for this, for a year now I've had no idea what cursors even are but got the thing working in a jiffy after your suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

Get the Table into the memory using a DataSet
and than run foreach DataRow , get the mail and send it...

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean each time a new row is added (e.g. order is placed)? If so, you can use a [Trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) to send the email each time a row is inserted or updated.

Comment: There's a job that's run every few hours or so, and that needs to check back on all the new rows. I suppose a trigger is a good alternative for doing just this but I'm not sure how that would react to the huge sum of other data that needs to be there before the data is complete enough for mailing. The actual table has relations all over the place so depending on things the trigger might fire too early.